# Change source file for tmux

Tags: tmux

After setting tmux to read a conf file:

```
bind r source-file ~/config/tmux/tmux.sh
```

I'm trying to change it to a different file, but I keep receiving the same error:

```
-bash: ~/.config/tmux/tmux.sh: No such file or directory
```

My first attempt was running `bind r source-file` again, but with a different target. I read all the manuals, tried to find the persistent confs for tmux, and even tried `uninstall --purge`. But, it keeps pointing to the same file.

I must be doing something utterly stupid...

I want to bind it to something like:

```
~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf
```

Side question: where does tmux store the current confs? If I was able to reinstall it and still see the same stuff, some env/files must remain somewhere...

Comment: Do you have a `~/.tmux.conf` file?

Comment: I don't. And I really don't where tmux stores the results of `bind r source-file`.